# What's the meaning of the first two lines occurring after opening a Terminal window?

Tags: terminal

I have an issue when I'm connected to public Wi-Fi networks with my Terminal,
When I run it, I see the following:

```
Last login: Sun Jul 26 11:58:02 on ttys001
Inbal-TOSH:~ chen$
```

'Inbal-TOSH' is a name of a computer in the network I guess. but I don't understand why am I seeing it.

Comment: Your question doesn't match the description. Which question are you asking? Are you asking "what's the meaning of…" or are you asking "why is my hostname incorrect"? Do you want to know what the meaning of the "Last login" line is? Do you want to know what the various pieces of information in the prompt mean?

Answer (score 1):

Hostname can be set by the wifi network's DHCP server, but you can turn this off - see https://superuser.com/questions/49891/how-can-i-stop-mac-os-x-overriding-my-hostname-when-i-receive-a-dhcp-request-on

Answer (score 0):

Go into System Preferences > Sharing. "Inbal-TOSH" should be the Computer Name at the top of that pane. The rest of that line is your username showing that you are at the root of your user folder: "/Users/Chen"

If that is incorrect then there is something very strange going on with your Mac. Someone may have messed around with your shell defaults, usually one of the BASH profile files or as much as I hate to say it, possibly some malware of some sort.

Comment: It's not and its changes

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode (Shift key while booting) and create another administrative account. If it still happens the issue is with the OS. If it does not the issue is with that user account.